# xcode distribute the ipa with "in house" method

Tags: ios, enterprise, ota

xcode distribute the ipa with "in house" method,and then I deployit in OTA and ios devices install it from safari.The first time I open the app running time will be prompted“whether to allow a certain company"，how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The alert shown when trying to install a new app outside of the App Store is provided and presented by iOS, you can not prevent it from happening. The text displayed is partially taken from the app and the OTA manifest file so you can have a small influence on what the alert says, but basically just the name.